# What is the purpose of thicker washers?

Tags: hardware

I've seen flat washers that have the same diameter, but vary in thickness.

[image]

How does depth affect a washer?

What is the best application for a thin washer? What is the best application for a thick washer?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Might it be as simple as "to space something further away or closer from something else"?

Comment: Some washers like fender washers are much thinner they form better to the surface where a washer like the one shown are for strength the bolt head will not easily deform these and possibly pull through a larger hole where a fender washer may deform and not hold as well.

Comment: The pictured washer might be most often used to keep a moving part (ie. wheel or blades) from the stationary part to which it is attached.  A thinner one, of the same outer dia., might be most often used when a screw is being used in a pre-drilled hole that is almost the same size as the head of the screw or slightly larger; especially if it's being used on a metal object.  Fender washers are most often used when the material is relatively fragile (ie. thin metal or peg board).  Carriage bolts, securing (ie) 2x8's or 4x's, require a thick washer that's nearly twice the width of the bolt head.

Comment: "Carriage bolts, securing (ie) 2x8's or 4x's, require a thick washer that's nearly twice the width of the bolt head." Why so? I cannot imagine that a standard thin washer would deform, since the tension is applied evenly. I've never seen a deformed washer before.